# CSS being applied to all elements, not just the class

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, webkit

This issue is occurring entirely within an `<iframe>`

The CSS looks like this

```
*{-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);}.page{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;visibility:hidden}
```

My `.page` styles are being applied to everything in the `<iframe>`, even though they should only apply to `.page` classed elements

If I use chrome web inspector to edit the `<style>` tag, and put a space after `-webkit-touch-callout` then press enter, everything seems to re-render correctly, though I don't think CSS requires a space there...

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue? I see the same thing in Safari, and editting the style tag works there as well, but I need something that works before the webpage renders

The associated style is within `<iframe>` `<head>` `<style>`

[image]

Comment: .page or .sproutPage?

Comment: `.sproutPage` but same difference -- see answer below

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, so it turns out the style `.sproutPage` isn't actually being applied to the elements, even though it shows up in the styles panel -- I realized this because `visibility: hidden` would make everything invisible, but only does so once I've toggled it off and on

In the end, its just some webkit inspection bug